# MongoDB Contacts to xConnect Migration Error

Tags: xconnect, mongodb

I've searched everywhere in the internet and I couldn't really find anything associated to this.

We are migrating Sitecore 8 Mongo Db to Sitecore 9 XConnect database. We followed the steps from below article:

https://neilkillen.com/2017/11/29/how-to-migrate-your-sitecore-8-x-mongodb-contacts-to-xconnect/

We've installed:

- Data Exchange Framework 2.0.1 rev. 180108 MongoDB Provider for Data
- Exchange Framework 2.0.2 rev. 180619 Sitecore Provider for Data
- Exchange Framework 2.0.1 rev. 180108 xConnect Provider for Data
- Exchange Framework 2.0.2 rev. 180619 xDB Data Migration Tool for Data
- Exchange Framework 2.0.2 rev. 180619

[image]

And we've connected successfully to Endpoints but When we ran Batch Pipeline in Verfy mode, we have the following error.

If someone knows how to fix it please help us. Thanks.

> ManagedPoolThread #6 08:57:29 INFO [Data Exchange] Starting pipeline
> batch processing. (pipeline batch: MongoDB Contacts to xConnect
> Migration, mode: Verify)
>
> ManagedPoolThread #6 08:57:29 ERROR [Data
> Exchange] An error occurred when trying to read data from MongoDB.
> (pipeline: Read Contacts from MongoDB Pipeline, pipeline step: Read
> Contacts from MongoDB, pipeline step identifier:
> 24e95bb0-6786-4f7b-8bc9-9cb140f98710, collection: Contacts, endpoint:
> Mongo Database Endpoint)
>
> ManagedPoolThread #6 08:57:29 ERROR [Data
> Exchange] And cannot be called with zero queries. Parameter name:
> queries (pipeline: Read Contacts from MongoDB Pipeline, pipeline step:
> Read Contacts from MongoDB, pipeline step identifier:
> 24e95bb0-6786-4f7b-8bc9-9cb140f98710)
>
> ManagedPoolThread #6 08:57:29
> ERROR [Data Exchange] at
> MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.And(IEnumerable`1 queries) at
> Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.MongoDB.FilterExpressions.RandomSizeQueryBuilder.Build(MongoQueryContext
> context) at
> Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.MongoDB.PipelineSteps.ReadMongoDBDocumentsVerificationStepProcessor.GetQuery(Endpoint
> endpoint, PipelineStep pipelineStep, PipelineContext pipelineContext,
> ILogger logger) at
> Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.MongoDB.Processors.PipelineSteps.ReadMongoDBDocumentsStepProcessor.ReadData(Endpoint
> endpoint, PipelineStep pipelineStep, PipelineContext pipelineContext,
> ILogger logger)
>
> ManagedPoolThread #6 08:57:29 ERROR [Data Exchange]
> Pipeline step processing will abort because a critical error occurred
> during processing. (pipeline: Read Contacts from MongoDB Pipeline,
> pipeline step: Read Contacts from MongoDB)
>
> ManagedPoolThread #6
> 08:57:29 ERROR [Data Exchange] Pipeline processing will abort because
> a critical error occurred during processing. (pipeline batch: MongoDB
> Contacts to xConnect Migration, pipeline: Read Contacts from MongoDB
> Pipeline, pipeline processor:
> Sitecore.DataExchange.Processors.Pipelines.PipelineProcessor, mode:
> Verify)

Comment: What if just run in a default mode? I see it was run in Verify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the way we are executing the process. We found this out after talking to Sitecore Support.

Note From Sitecore Support:
Verification feature is slightly different. In order to run migration with enabled verification feature you need to perform all steps from the installation guide for enabling verification feature (1.6.5. Configure the verification database) and then click "Run pipeline batch" button(not Run in Verify mode).

[Not Run in Verify mode], instead just click on "Run pipeline batch" button we were able to by pass the issue.